# Implementing an awfull long function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function

$$
f(\tau, X_1, X_2, V_1, V_2) = \  e^{A(\tau) + z_1 X_1 + z_2 X_2 + B_1(\tau)V_1 + B_2(\tau)V_2+ B_m(\tau)V_m}
$$
That I want to implement and do some numerics on in MATLAB. 
The thing is that its awfully long when inserting $A(\tau), B_1 (\tau), B_2 (\tau)$ and $B_m(\tau)$. E.g.

$$
B_m(\tau) = - \frac{z_1 \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{1m} + z_2 \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} + \\
     \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{1m}^2(z_1^2 - z_1) + \sigma_{2m}^2(z_2^2 - z_2) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} z_1 z_2}{\sigma_m^2} - \left( \frac{z_1 \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m}\rho_{1m} + z_2 \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \right)^2} \\
     \cdot \\
     \tan \Bigg( \sqrt{\sigma_m^2( \sigma_{1m}^2(z_1^2- z_1) + \sigma_{2m}^2 (z_2^2 - z_2) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} z_1z_2 ) - (z_1 \sigma_{1m} \sigma_m \rho_{1m} + z_2 \sigma_{2m} \sigma_m \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m)^2} \\   \left( \frac{\tau + C_m}{2} \right)\Bigg) \\
with \\
C_m = \frac{2 \arctan \left(\frac{z_1 \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{1m} + z_2 \sigma_{2m} \sigma_{m} \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m}{\sigma_m^2} \right) }{\sqrt{\sigma_m^2( \sigma_{1m}^2(z_1^2- z_1) + \sigma_{2m}^2 (z_2^2 - z_2) + \sigma_{1m} \sigma_{2m} \rho_{12m} z_1z_2 ) - (z_1 \sigma_{1m} \sigma_m \rho_{1m} + z_2 \sigma_{2m} \sigma_m \rho_{2m} - \kappa_m)^2}}
$$

So implementing this by just typing everything in will with high probability result in multiple small errors, taking week to find.

In best of worlds I would do something like

> A = @(t) ...
>
> B_1 = @(t) ...
>
> B_2 = @(t) ...

and then

> f = @(...) exp( A + z_1X_1 + z_2X_2 + B_1V_1 ...)

But to my knowledge this is not possible. Thus I'm looking for helpful advice on how to implement such a function, reducing the probability of human error as much as possible.

**Useful information**
Actually for the task Im about to do, I will wary $z_i$ and the rest will be known. So basically it boils down to
$$
f(z_1,z_2) = e^{A(z_1,z_2) + z_1X_1 + z_2X_2 + B_1(z_1, z_2)V_1 + B_2(z_1, z_2)V_2 + B_m(z_1, z_2)V_m}
$$

Comment: You can do the thing you think is not possible. You can also simply put the function in its own m-file and calculate the values one by one, storing them in intermediate variables.

Comment: @dbx I have to send the whole function into an optimizer at the end. And Im going to use a routine done by matlab so I have to send it as one piece! But how does one define $f(g(x))$ in matlab?

Comment: Can you define the function in an m-file named myFun.m, then pass the function to the optimizer by writing @myFun as one of the arguments to the optimizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make multiple inline functions, and use other functions inside an inline function definition, like so:

```
f1=@(x)(x^2+1);
f2=@(x)(x+5);
g=@(x)(f1(f2(x)));
g(5)

ans =
   101
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it. :)